# Isolated a segfault - but why is it happening?

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

Using the DevC++ debugger (still new to it), I'm pretty sure I've isolated a segfault scenario, but I've got no idea why it's happening.

```
void LinkedList::Add(const char *Word){
    ListNode *newNode = new ListNode;
    strcpy(newNode->Word, Word);
    newNode->Next = NULL;
    ...
}
```

A segfault occurs at the "newNode->Next = NULL;". However if I remove the strcpy above it, the segfault does not occur (but it means my newNode->Word is empty)

EDIT: sorry guys, here is the ListNode:

```
struct ListNode
{
    char *Word;
    LNodePtr Next;
};
```

Comment: We need to see the definition of ListNode.

Comment: This problem can probably be solved if you use `std::string` instead of `char *` to represent strings. In this case you do a simple assignment.

Comment: Can you post the structure of `ListNode`?

Comment: How are you allocating memory for `newNode->Word`?

Comment: While not causing the problem, I'll change my strcpy to strncpy(newNode->Word, Word, cMaxLen); for safety. Ty for the tip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not allocated any memory for `Word` pointer in the `ListNode` structure. Without this, it is pointing to some random location and whenever you are trying to write to that location (using `strcpy`) you will get an access violation. The simplest way to solve this is to use the `std::string` class and get rid of all manual memory management.

If you really want to use `char*`, then write a constructor for `ListNode` which takes `const char*` parameter (remember to declare it as `explicit` though) and use the `strlen` to find the length of the input string. Then allocate `len + 1` (extra one `char` for the NULL terminator) characters and store the address in `Word` pointer. After that you can do `strncpy`.

Comment: I see my problem now, thank you. Unfortunately I'm going to have to stick to manual memory management for now as my assignment dictates such.

Comment: I just read your edit, I'll try that! For now, simply adding "newNode->Word = new char[cMaxLen]" before the strncpy has worked. cMaxLen being 100. I understand it makes the dynamicness of it pointless, but it will let me work the rest of the program for now.

Comment: @Paul: don't forget to release the memory in the destructor, or else you will be leaking.

Answer (score 4):

If the `Word` member is a pointer, your `strcpy` will overwrite unallocated memory.

After that, most operations can fail.

Using `std::string` instead of `const char*` will save you in many places.

Comment: You are assuming no memory is allocated in `ListNode` constructor for `Word` pointer.

Comment: @Naveen - Yes, or not enough memory. Seeing the `const char *Word` parameter just makes me believe that the other `Word` looks the same. The fact that he initializes members in `Add` suggests that the constructor doesn't do much.

Answer (score 1):

`strcpy` is fine but very dangerous, it make a copy of your chars until it reaches a `\0`. If your `Word` do not contain any \0, it will copy a lot of stuff into you `newNode->Word` pointer.

The other potential danger is the way you initialize the `newNode->Word`, did you allocate enough room to make the string copy?

Answer (score 0):

throwing a guess out there.. I'd hazard that in your `ListNode` implementation, `Word` is a `char*`, and it's not initialized to point to a valid block of memory (could be null) - `strcpy()` does not automatically allocate space, it assumes there is enough space at the destination. And here, it's trying to copy the string to a null pointer (or uninitialized pointer) - hence the segfault...